# Correct way to architect an single insert event from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, clean-architecture

Imagine that I have a simple modal with static data rendered.
This data is passed as an `Parcelable` argument to the modal `fragment`. When the modal is opened, I want to add it to the `userHistory database`, a simple insert which I don't expect any kind of return.

To do this implementation, I did ->

- A Fragment that renders the data
- A DAO (with Room) that inserts the data to the database
- A repository which calls the DAO query

But I'm in an internal question about how to call the `repository.insertPage` from `Fragment`.

**Is it bad add the repository reference into fragment?**

**Should I create a `viewmodel` just with a function to make the proxy on `OnCreateView` that calls the repository?**

**Should I create a `useCase` that calls the repository and reference the `usecase` on `Fragment`?**

Honestly I think that the best approach is reference the repository in the `fragment`, bud I don't know if it's a bad design.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it bad add the repository reference into fragment?

What you describe is called a **relaxed layered architecture** where dependencies may bypass lower layers. Simon Brown describes it in chapter 34, *The Missing Chapter*, of the Clean Architecture book.

[image: Relaxed layered architecture]

Robert C. Martin (2017), *[Clean Architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clean-architecture-a/9780134494272/)*

The opposite of the relaxed layered architecture is a **strict layered architecture** where arrows should always point downward on the next adjacent lower layer.

There might be some situations when it is ok to bypass the domain layers. But only if there is no business logic in between. This is usually not the case. Usually you have at least validation logic.

> Should I create a useCase that calls the repository and reference the usecase on Fragment?

In the clean architecture you usually pass entity objects to the repository, not request objects like a `Parcelable`. Entity objects ensure application agnostic domain rules. Thus you should first convert the data (the Parcelable) into entity objects and then pass these to the repostitory. You usually do this in a use case or interactor which implements application specific domain rules.

Maybe the result of that use case is that it just forwards the data to the entity and then to the repository. If so it means that there is no domain logic in the use case nor the entity, even no validation. This is often a hint that you implement an anemic domain model. In such cases it might be ok to directly call the repository.

But first you should try as hard as you can to maintain the architecture. Every bypass is an exception from the default architecture rules and thus weakens the architecture by making it more arbitrary. Maintaining an architecture is hard, because you must resist to create bypasses for exceptional cases. But if exceptions are the norm you might use the wrong architecture or you apply it in a wrong way.